# Can someone tell me why this while loop works in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

```
sum, Nr = 0, 12
i = Nr
while i:
    sum += i
    i -= 1
print ('The sum of all natural numbers up to (and inclusive of) ' + repr(Nr) +
' is ' + repr(sum))
```

So this is a very simple while loop in python 3 which returns "The sum of all natural numbers up to (and inclusive of) 12 is 78" as expected.

What I am confused about is that why this condition "while i:" works here when "i" is not subjected to any comparison operator.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that negative numbers are also truthy... so don't change that `i -= 1` to anything that isn't going to exactly match `0` and end the loop... eg: `i -= 7` will never end...

Comment: Thanks! I just started programming and truthy falsy helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In conditional statements, the input is implicitly cast to boolean, hence the loop is equivalent to

```
while bool(i):
    ...
```

`bool(i)` is `True` as long as `i != 0`, and `False` if `i == 0`, so the loop goes until `i` becomes zero.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Python does an implicit replacement with `i not equals zero` (pseudo code). See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html).

Answer (score 1):

`While` expect the expression and if it is `true` is runs the loop.

> while_stmt ::= "while" expression ":" suite
>                    ["else" ":" suite]

```
In [38]: bool(Nr)
Out[38]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

`while` loop expects any condition either `True` or `False`. When you write `while i` (suppose `i = 5`) it is evaluated as `True`, so the loop continues but when it encounters `i=0` it is evaluated as `False` and the loop breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Python automatically computes the `truthy` value of the variable passed to it by converting it into boolean. Since `i` being a non-zero positive integer is considered true in Python, that's why it's working, till it finally becomes 0 which is considered false.

```
>>> print(bool(3))
True
>>> print(bool(0))
False
```

Comment: 0 is definitely not considered negative.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

In python, values are duck typed - what this means is that the interpreter can try to fit the value into whatever context you have put it. All numbers other than zero are 'truthy', so for instance

```
if 3:  # True
```

Whereas zero is falsy:

```
if 0:  # False
```

Comment: all values _below_ zero are also truthy.

Comment: corrected the answer @Jean-FrançoisFabre :)